# Adding a condition to function so that it runs only in specific situations

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a text game in javascript right now and have a function to pick up a sword.

```
var takeSword = function() {
        if (currentRoom.hasSword) {
            $("<p>You picked up a sword.</p>").properDisplay();

        }
        else {
            $("<p>The sword is not here.</p>").properDisplay();
        }
    };
```

My problem is, as long as you're in the same room as the sword, you can pick it up over and over.  How can you set the function so that once you pick up the sword you can't pick it up again?

My original thought was setting a variable like `var sword = false;` and then when the function runs to set `sword = true;` but that didn't work.

This isn't my entire code, there's an object further up that sets `hasSword = true;' so that the sword can be picked up in the first place and can NOT be picked up in different rooms of the game.

Comment: You can mark the `currentRoom` with the the status of the sword picking like this `currentRoom.swordPicked = true`

Comment: Why not set `hasSword` to `false` after picking it up?

Comment: `currentRoom.hasSword = false; player.hasSword = true;`?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - unfortunately, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Kenney - thanks!  I didn't do it quite the way you did it, but you got me in the right directions.  I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
var GameState = {
    worldHasSword: true,
    playerHasSword: false,
    takeSword: function() {
        if( this.worldHasSword ) {
            this.worldHasSword = false;
            this.playerHasSword = true;
            $("<p>You picked up a sword.</p>").properDisplay();
        }
        else {
            $("<p>The sword is not here.</p>").properDisplay();
        }
    }
}

GameState.takeSword();
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is not to touch your original function at all, but simply *wrap* it in a general function that will prevent its being called more than once.  This general function can be used anywhere else in your code that you need to "once-ify" something:

```
function once(fn, context) { 
    var result;

    return function() { 
        if(fn) {
            result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
            fn = null;
        }

        return result;
    };
}
```

Now you simply do:

```
var takeSwordOnce = once(takeSword);
```

and use `takeSwordOnce` in your code.  Or, you can do:

```
takeSword = once(takeSword);
```

Please see [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once) for further explanation of the `once` function.

Answer (score 0):

@Kenney got me thinking in the right direction.  Here's how I fixed it without totally rewriting the function:

```
var takeSword = function() {
        if (currentRoom.hasSword) {
            $("<p>You picked up a sword.</p>").properDisplay();
            currentRoom.hasSword = false;
        }
        else {
            $("<p>The sword is not here.</p>").properDisplay();
        }
    };
```

The first mistake I made was thinking "hasSword" was the variable by itself.  I needed to add the currentRoom to it then it worked fine.  I've tested it and also tried it in rooms where the sword does not exist and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: You're probably going to want to keep track of how many swords the player is carrying aswell! Maybe there are other things to pick up too?

Comment: @Kenney - agreed.  I think I'm going to have to go with some type of `for` loop or `forEach` to start rolling through different inventory items.   Because I'm learning this from scratch, I pick a path to get 1 thing to work and after I  understand that go back and figure out how to make it work with multiple things.  (ie.  I can now pick up 1 item and not pick it up twice.  Now, how do I do that with 5 items?)  -- that's the next step.

Comment: Yes indeed - a very good approach! I'll let you get on with it ;-)

Comment: That is a prototyping approach to development. Just beware that you will likely reach a point where you have to rewrite whole slabs of code to accommodate some new functionality. That is what design processes are supposed to avoid (and why prototypes are usually kept absolutely minimal). Good luck. :-)

Comment: It's also called [Iterative/Incremental Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development): *"The basic idea behind this method is to develop a system through repeated cycles (iterative) and in smaller portions at a time (incremental), allowing software developers to take advantage of what was learned during development of earlier parts or versions of the system."*